# Can we create an ACL for GCS objects where access requires membership in more than one group?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Suppose I have content in GCS with a pre-existing set of ACLs (assume fine-grained ACLs for the moment - setting aside IAM-based permissions for the moment). So, for example, I have a bucket "my_bucket" and I have an entity within "my_bucket", "red_stuff".  "red_stuff" has acls that allow access to the content if you are part of the group "ISeeRedStuff". Similarly, I might have lots of other files, that are created with an ACL that grants access based on membership in the group "ISeeRedStuff", but I might also have content and ACLs based on membership in the group "ISeeBlueStuff".

Now, through some mechanism, I discover that "red_stuff" includes some sensitive information, such as Credit Card Numbers, or SSNs, etc. What I would like to do is to modify the permissions for "red_stuff" to allow access for a user if they have membership in both "ISeeRedStuff" as well as "ISeeSensitiveStuff". Note that not all people in "ISeeSensitiveStuff" may have access to "ISeeRedStuff", so I cannot simply replace the group permissions. What I want is a logical-and operation.

I know that I can build a group "ISeeSenstiveRedStuff" from the existing ACLs, but synchronizing the content for this with the other groups is a headache. Moreover, if I want to track different membership viewing rights based on different kinds of sensitive information, then the number of groups can grow large if I use the mechanism of creating more groups to hold the different combinations.

Am I missing something in the documentation? I did not see any means of defining such a capability.

EDIT:
I considered the idea of using signed URLs to generate permissions instead to address this problem. Basically, move permissions calculation to an Application Server, and have the server generate signed URLs to allow access to the content. However, this can get to be a messy solution for many reasons.

Comment: I posted an answer, but as an aside, if you discover later on that people had access to sensitive material that they shouldn't have, it seems like the damage is already done (since they could have already accessed it and stored it elsewhere).  Regardless, to prevent further damage you would need to distinguish sensitive from non-sensitive material and modify group memberships and ACLs to match.  In my opinion, maintaining and reasoning about a complex hierarchy of logical-ANDs only creates a different set of problems.

Comment: Agreed, that it's not ideal: we would need to maintain the logical-and relation between the groups, which implies a polling process and automatic update process when group memberships change. In our use-case, we are exactly looking for the situation where the 'damage is already done,' and we are trying to repair it. It's unclear how to avoid the complexity. :( Encrypting the content is another idea, but that adds other complexity. In any case, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of "logical-AND" in Google Cloud Storage access control.  If a user is a member of any group with access, then the user is allowed access.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. Are there any plans to consider adding logical principal expressions? Where might I submit this idea as a feature request?